# How to set Mail.app to always open URL's in the external browser in the background?

Tags: mail.app, web-browser, url

I'm on Mountain Lion and in Apple Mail whenever I click a link in an email it opens my browser in front of Mail.

I'd like to keep reading the email and open all links behind Mail, then switch to my browser and read the links later.

I'm aware of right clicking a link and selecting "Open Link Behind Mail", and I know of the "command-click" method to achieve that. But I want that to be the default behavior, so I don't have to do any extra clicking, I just want the links to **always** open in the background. How do I set it to do that?

Comment: I think "CMD-click" is the only way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to make Apple Mail open all links in a browser behind
>   Mail without the need to right click?

Command-click the link (same thing in Safari will open links in a background tab).

Comment: The question is asking, how do make Apple Mail open all links behind Mail without the need to right click or command-click? We'd like all links to open behind Mail when you click them without the need to do anything extra.